# How to change link href by link text

Tags: jquery

I have a text below where I want to swap out the login link, but only if the text says "Log In". Sometimes is will say "My Account":

```
<div id="Login_T4304F19B025">
    <a href="/login1">Log in</a>
</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to change the href to /login2 if the link text is "Log in"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('#Login_T4304F19B025 a').text() == 'Log in'){
  $('#Login_T4304F19B025 a').attr('href','/login2');
}else{
  $('#Login_T4304F19B025 a').attr('href','/login1');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:contains()`:

```
$("a:contains('Log In')").prop("href", "/login2");
```

However, `:contains()` works like a wildcard match (e.g. it would also match *"Please Log In Now"*).  If you want a more restrictive search, use `.filter()`:

```
$("a").filter(function () { 
    return $.text(this) == "Log In";
}).prop("href", "/login2");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div a").attr("href","some link to somewhere");
```

hope this works

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
  $('a:contains("Log in")').attr('href', '/login2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('#Login_T4304F19B025 a').text();

if(a == "Log in" || a == "My account"){
    a.attr("//new link");
}
```